# Magento combine normal navigation with layered navigation

Tags: magento, navigation

Is it possible to combine both normal menu navigation with layered navigation in getChildHtml(left)?

What I'm, trying to achieve looks like this:

```
/* normal fixed nav */
Beachwear
    Tops
    Accessories
Tops
Shoes
Bags

/* layered/filter nav */
Colour
    Red
    Blue
    Yellow
```

I know I somehow need to merge catalog/navigation/left.phtml with catalog/layer/view.phtml, but I'm not sure how possible this is or how to do it.

Any advice greatly appreciated.